# Sum of modulus of complex numbers : $|\sin(z)|+|\cos(z)| \geq 1$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

> I'm trying to establish if $|\sin(z)|+|\cos(z)|$ is greater than or equal to $1$.

I have tried to write out the expression in exponential form, but I don't really arrive at anything useful.

I would really appreciate any help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assume that $|\sin(z)|+|\cos(z)|<1$ squarinq we obtain $2|\sin(z)||\cos(z)|<0$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Are you assuming that $|\sin z\,|^2=\sin^2 z$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$? This is absurd.

Answer (score 1):

Writing $w=e^{iz}$ and using the definition of $\sin z$ and $\cos z$, the inequality becomes equivalent to
$$
|w^2-1|+|w^2+1|\ge2|w|
$$
(for $w\ne0$, but it is trivial for $w=0$).

It is not restrictive to prove the squared inequality; we get
$$
(w^2-1)(\bar{w}^2-1)+(w^2+1)(\bar{w}^2+1)+2|w^4-1|\ge4w\bar{w}
$$
that reduces to
$$
w^2\bar{w}^2+1+|w^4-1|\ge2w\bar{w}
$$
(where all terms are real) so to
$$
(w\bar{w}-1)^2+|w^4-1|\ge0
$$
which is true.